# netplan config for eap-gtc

Tags: networking, 20.04, wireless, netplan

I have a number of 20.04 systems that connect to WPA2-Enterprise networks. I use Netplan to connect and typically use eap-peap to for authentication. I just got a request to setup a system at a site that uses eap-gtc. I do not see an option for this in the netplan documentation and am wondering if anyone has gotten this to work. My typical config looks like:

```
MySSID:
  auth:
    identity: "XXXXXXX" 
    password: "XXXXXXX"
    key-management: eap 
    method: peap 
    phase2-auth: MSCHAPV2
```

According to the netplan documentation the options for method are tls,
peap, and ttls, but nothing about gtc.

Any ideas on how my config should look?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
phase2-auth: MSCHAPV2
```

to:

```
phase2-auth: GTC
```